# print value of key in nested hash in ruby without loop

Tags: ruby, hash

```
irb(main):024:0> outer_hash={:x=>in_hash, :y=>another_in_hash}
=> {:x=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}, :y=>{:l=>4, :m=>5, :n=>6}}
```

> I wish to print inner hash key and value without loop.

Comment: And how you imagine that?
How should looks like output?

Comment: `a = {:x=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}, :y=>{:l=>4, :m=>5, :n=>6}}`
`a.values.join(" ")`
 `=> "{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3} {:l=>4, :m=>5, :n=>6}"`
above is without loop but to print key and value separately you need to use loop.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the exact question that was stated:

```
▶ hash.inspect.gsub(/:\w+=>{/, '').gsub(/[{}:>]/, '')
#⇒ "a=1, b=2, c=3, l=4, m=5, n=6"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for something like this:

```
>> outer_hash.map { |_,v| v }
=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}, {:l=>4, :m=>5, :n=>6}]
```

or this:

```
>> outer_hash.map { |_,v| v.to_a }
=> [[[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]], [[:l, 4], [:m, 5], [:n, 6]]]
```